# Cannot compile parameterized mintingPolicy to Plutus

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, minting, plutustx

I tried compiling a solution from the examples provided in PPP Iteration #2 but got stuck. Any ideas?

**Code:** https://github.com/ILIYANGERMANOV/cardano-smart-contracts/blob/main/ivy-token/src/MintIvy.hs

**Error:**

```
...
Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName>_N)) ; PlutusTx.Eq.N:Eq[0]
                                                                                                                                                             <Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName>_N))
                                                                :: GHC.Types.Coercible
                                                                     Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName
                                                                     PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.BuiltinByteString))
                                                       (MintIvy.ivyToken
                                                        `cast` (Sym (Nth:2
                                                                         (Nth:3
                                                                              (((Sym (Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.N:TokenName[0])
                                                                                 ->_R Sym (Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.N:TokenName[0])
                                                                                 ->_R <GHC.Types.Bool>_R) ; Sym (PlutusTx.Eq.N:Eq[0]
                                                                                                                     <Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName>_N)) ; PlutusTx.Eq.N:Eq[0]
                                                                                                                                                                  <Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName>_N)))
                                                                :: GHC.Types.Coercible
                                                                     Plutus.V1.Ledger.Value.TokenName
                                                                     PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.BuiltinByteString))
                                                of {
                                                  GHC.Types.False -> GHC.Types.False;
                                                  GHC.Types.True ->
                                                    PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.ifThenElse
                                                      @ GHC.Types.Bool
                                                      (PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.equalsInteger
                                                         amt MintIvy.initialAmount)
                                                      GHC.Types.True
                                                      GHC.Types.False
                                                }
                                            };
                                          : _ [Occ=Dead] _ [Occ=Dead] -> GHC.Types.False
                                        }
                                        }
                                    }
                               of {
                                 GHC.Types.False ->
                                   PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.trace
                                     @ GHC.Types.Bool
                                     (GHC.Magic.noinline
                                        @ (GHC.Base.String -> PlutusTx.Builtins.Internal.BuiltinString)
                                        PlutusTx.Builtins.Class.stringToBuiltinString
                                        (GHC.CString.unpackCString# "wrong amount minted"#))
                                     GHC.Types.False;
                                 GHC.Types.True -> GHC.Types.True
                               }
                           }
                           }
                           }
**Context: Compiling definition of: MintIvy.mkPolicy
Context: Compiling expr: MintIvy.mkPolicy
Context: Compiling expr: PlutusTx.Base..
                           @ (() -> Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.ScriptContext -> GHC.Types.Bool)
                           @ Ledger.Typed.Scripts.MonetaryPolicies.WrappedMintingPolicyType
                           @ MintIvy.MintingIvyParam
                           (Ledger.Typed.Scripts.MonetaryPolicies.wrapMintingPolicy
                              @ () PlutusTx.IsData.Instances.$fUnsafeFromData())
                           MintIvy.mkPolicy
Context: Compiling expr at "ivy-token-0.1.0.0-inplace:MintIvy:(93,8)-(93,69)"**
`
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason checking for equality with the `TokenName` type isn't possible on-chain (at least that's my theory, maybe `TokenName` itself is not acceptable). Still, you can define your token as a builtin byte string and then compare that to the token name using pattern mathcing.

So you would have

```
{-# INLINABLE ivyToken #-}
ivyToken :: BuiltinByteString
ivyToken = "IVY_T1"
```

Where `BuiltinByteString` is imported from `PlutusTx.Prelude`

```
checkMintedAmount :: Bool
checkMintedAmount = case flattenValue (txInfoMint info) of
    [(cs, (TokenName tn'), amt)] -> cs  == ownCurrencySymbol ctx && tn' == ivyToken && amt == initialAmount
    _                -> False
```